# Имеется задача определения нахождения точки внутри эллипса

Tags: алгоритм

Необходимо написать код, который будет определять нахождение точки внутри эллипса (нахождение ее на границе эллипса является верным).

Comment: Берите формулу эллипса, подставляйте координаты точки, смотрите, что получается...

Comment: Извините, но ответа Вашего я не понял. Можно подробнее?

Comment: Надо не выгугливать, а брать определение эллипса и немного подумать. На гугляже далеко не уедешь.

Comment: **1**. *Учебные задания нужно делать самостоятельно*. **2**. Вы не указали даже, в каком виде задан эллипс и какой именно - он может быть повернутым, смещенным, задан в разных системах координат... **3**. Вы даже не указали язык программирования :)

Comment: язык тут не важен. для меня важно найти ответ понимания поиска принадлежности точки  к эллипсу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Формула для эллипса

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

a и b - это полуоси.

Если подставлять в нее координаты точки, полученные значения будут положительными для точек вне эллипса, нулевыми для точек на границе и отрицательными для внутренних.

Comment: Осталось объяснить человеку, что делать в случае, например, повернутого и смещенного эллипса :) А потом написать код. Вобщем, раз уж начали - сделать за него домашку...

Comment: За меня писать код не надо. Туго было с эллипсами. Вектор вы задали. Благодарю